# Using a variable for table name in 'From' clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a UDF that queries data out of a table. The table, however, needs to be definable as a parameter. For example I can't have:

**Select * From [dbo].[TableA]**

I need something like:

**Select * From [dbo].[@TableName]**

The above line doesn't work, and also the UDF prohibits me from setting the query as a string and calling exec(). I can do this in a procedure, but I can't call the procedure from the UDF either.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this within the UDF without having some kind of massive switch statement?

Comment: I was trying to do that exact thing the other day with no luck. I hope someone knows!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can't be done, dynamic SQL is not supported in functions.

See this SO question:
[Executing dynamic SQL in a SQLServer 2005 function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150552/executing-dynamic-sql-in-a-sqlserver-2005-function)

Comment: This answer is correct when using normal UDFs (which is what I asked about). I was able to solve my problem with a CLR UDF written in C#.

Answer (score 21):

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @table
EXEC (@SQL)  -- parentheses are required
```

Comment: You may have gotten a negative vote because this leaves you open to a SQL Injection attack depending on how you use this query.  EDIT: I just noticed that DaveK said he can't do this in the question - That's probably where your downvote came from.

Answer (score 5):

You can UNION ALL your tables and include the table name as a column, then specify the table name as a predicate over this. If you check the query plan for this example you see that t2 is not touched

```
create table t1 (i int)
create table t2 (i int)

insert t1 values(1)
insert t1 values(2)
insert t1 values(3)
insert t2 values(4)
insert t2 values(5)
insert t2 values(6)


;with tableSet as (
    select i, 't1' as tableName from t1
    union all select i, 't2' as tableName from t2
)
select i from tableSet where tableName = 't1'
```

Comment: +1 the question excludes a "massive switch statement" approach tho

Comment: @Andomar, I thought this was a little less "switchy" than a bunch of if/else blocks. E.g. this set of tables to UNION ALL could be wrapped into a view if you had many functions that needed the functionality, which you couldn't do with if/else. Point taken though ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can write a udf clr that can do dynamic sql.  I've had to implement this before.  It's pretty slick.

Comment: Right, but that would be an extended CLR function, not a UDF?

Comment: Can it be used in a query the way a UDF can?

Comment: Yeah, but your DBA has to agree to enable CLR support, and you have to deploy them as a compiled .NET assmebly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(VS.80).aspx

Comment: This solution worked great. I was able to write a table-value CLR UDF in C#, with the sql query being generated dynamically. My regular UDF now calls the CLR UDF and assigns the returned values to parameters. I still have to do some scalability testing, but so far so good.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it. What problem are you solving, there might be other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you would give more details about what underlying problem you are trying to solve, we might have better answers.  One solution is to code generate the UDFs on a per-table basis.  Another is to use dynamic SQL from an SP.  What's right for your situation is hard to say.