# the name is not a valid identifier error in function

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
     Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fngetname]        
    (         
       @OrganisationID int=null,        
       @UserID int=null,        
       @ClientTypeID int        

    )        
    RETURNS  varchar(500)        
    BEGIN        
    DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(500)        

     DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(500)            
    set @dbName=(select ClientDataBase from dbo.ClientType where ClientTypeID=@ClientTypeID)       

    begin        

   set @Name='select UserName from ['+ @dbName+'].dbo.Users where UserID='+convert(varchar,@UserID)  
    exec @Name   
    end        

       return @Name                
    end
```

Comment: function code seems to raise no errors itself, what is your problem exactly?

Comment: when executing select dbo.fngetname(1,null,9) getting error. The name 'select UserName from [GMS_Latest].dbo.Users where UserID=1' is not a valid identifier

Comment: that suggests your error does not lie in the code you are showing us, but in the code calling that function - does that database `GMS_Latest` exist are you sure of it?

Comment: yes that is the database name

Answer (score 6):

There are two issues here, first if you want to execute dynamic sql, you need to **encapsulate your statement variable in parenthesises**:

you need to add parenthesises to the `exec @Name` in your function declaration.
The function gets written but cannot execute it stops at the `exec`

replace that `exec @Name` with `exec (@Name)`

you can easily reproduce this error by just trying two simple lines (ofc replace the table and db-name with something you have ;)):

```
DECLARE @statement VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM [nana].dbo.Fruits'
exec @statement
```

This should throw the exact same error.
Then add `()` around the `@statement` and it will work.

The second issue is, that **you cannot use dynamic sql in a function**, because they have to be deterministic ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150595/2186023)).

To get around this, rewrite that function behaviour into a stored procedure and then it should work ;).

One way to rewrite your function into a procedure might look like this(untested, because I do not have your database structure set up):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetName @OrganisationID INT = NULL, @UserID INT = NULL, @ClientTypeID INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(500)        
    DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(500)            
    SET @dbName = (SELECT ClientDataBase FROM dbo.ClientType WHERE ClientTypeID = @ClientTypeID)

    SET @Name = 'select UserName from [' + @dbName + '].dbo.Users where UserID=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @UserID)  
    exec(@Name)
END
GO
```

Comment: I am trying to execute your suggestion exec(@name) that follows this issue Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a function.

Comment: @user3350258 sorry for the trouble I edited my answer

Comment: @user3350258 what do you mean exactly? why not?

Comment: @user3350258 I added an example of how you could rewrite your function into a procedure

Comment: But I am using function in many stored procedures to generate a username

Comment: @user3350258 I am afraid then you will have to rewrite all calls to that function into calls to a procedure or you are out of luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`exec sp_executesql @statement`