# TSQL: Using parameter with tablename in function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-function, sql-server-2014

Using SQL Server 2014...

I'm trying to convert this code to be used in a function...

```
SET @sqlCommand = N'SELECT @text = ' + @fieldname + ' FROM ' + @tablename +' WHERE ID=''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200), @ID)  + ''''
EXECUTE sp_executesql...
```

...but functions doesn't accept sp_executesql.

How can I in a function get data from a table where the `tablename` is coming from a parameter?

Comment: @Tanner no duplicate there, my question is about dynamic in a FUNCTION.

Comment: Ok, have retracted, what's the reason for using a function rather than stored proc?

Comment: This is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150552/executing-dynamic-sql-in-a-sqlserver-2005-function

Comment: @Tanner I need to run the function many times during a single stored proc, so to keep code to a minimum I want to use functions.

Comment: @Tanner the similar question you refer to is for SQL Server 2005 - lots must have happen since then.

Comment: You haven't stated in the question or tags what version you're using

Answer (score -1):

Have no way to do this.
If you want you can use some options, like:

```
case when @TableName = 'X' then
   ...
when @TableName = 'Y' then
   ...
else
   ...
```

Comment: The whole idea is that I don't know the tablename.

Comment: But my answer is that have not way. And that true. please unvote-down

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
SET @sqlCommand = N'SELECT ' + @fieldname + ' FROM ' + @tablename +' WHERE ID=''' +   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200), @ID)  + ''''
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

I removed the '@text =' The reuslt wil be given by the query

Comment: Exec is not allowed in a function.

Comment: i see. Try converting the function in a stored procedure